# Vertical Aligned Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically I am trying to align two vertical button to the right hand side of my site. When I onclick, it will show another div with the help me jQuery animation. Here is my html code:

```
<div id="rightBar">
        <input type='button' id='hideshow' value='Show/Hide' />
        <input type='button' id='hideshowBookmark' value='Bookmark' />
        <div id='rightContent'>
            <table style="width:100%; text-align: center;padding: 2px;">
                <th colspan="2"><b>Get Directions</b></th>
                <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="120px"><label class="title">Get Location: </label></td>
                    <td><input id="txtFrom" type="text" class="textInput" placeholder="Outram" />&nbsp;<img id="AutoFrom" src="img/map.jpg" class="button_search" onclick="GetDataFrom();"/>&nbsp;<label class="title">To</label>&nbsp; <input id="txtTo" type="text" class="textInput" placeholder="Hougang mall" />&nbsp;<img id="AutoTo" src="img/map.jpg" class="button_search" onclick="GetDataTo();" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div id="divDirectionResults" style="display: none; border:1px solid black; opacity: 0.8; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=80); background:#000000; width:auto; height:190px;"></div>
            <table style="width:100%; text-align: center;padding: 2px;">   
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="padding-left:45px;"><input id="CbAvoid" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />&nbsp; Avoid ERP</td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 35%;">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input value="Get Routing" type="button" onClick="getDirections();" style="width: 109px; height: 23px;font-size:7pt;font-weight:bold;"/><input type="button" onclick="resetSearchField();" style="width: 58px; height: 23px;font-size: 7pt;font-weight:bold;" value="Reset"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div id="divComputedDirection">
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

And my JavaScript:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hideshow').click(function() {
        $('#rightContent').animate({
            width: 'toggle'
        }, 1000
                );
    });

    $('#hideshow').val('H\ni\nd\ne\n/\nS\nh\no\nw');
    $('#hideshowBookmark').val('B\no\no\no\nk\nm\na\nr\nk');
});
```

And the css:

```
#rightBar
{
    float: right;
}

#hideshow
{
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(#81BEF7,#2E9AFE);
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 0;
}
#hideshow:active
{
    outline:none;
}
#hideshowBookmark
{
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(#81BEF7,#2E9AFE);
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 0;
    margin-top: 170px;
}
#hideshowBookmark:active
{
    outline:none;
}

#rightContent
{
    width: 320px;
    height: 440px;
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
    margin-right: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

Somehow, the elements inside the div shifted down when I click on the first button. And my second button is not aligned to the right.

Here is my fiddle: [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/76FX8/)

I wonder why is it so? Is it because of my CSS or the way I put the html component?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the top margin and add a clear to the element. `Clear` does what it says, it clears floated elements from the flow.

Just change your CSS to this:

```
#hideshowBookmark
{
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(#81BEF7,#2E9AFE);
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 0;
    clear:both;
}
```

Here's the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cthulhu/76FX8/8/).

And here's some good documentation about [Clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear).

Comment: Just wonder do you know why when I slide the div out, all the components are moving? Do you know how to make their position stay?

Comment: That's not exactly a slide. You are using toggle with `width`, so the contents inside are adapting to the current width of the div as it expands. Search StackOverflow for a solution, if you don't find it you should open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tejashsoni111/76FX8/6/)

You need to add css to the div `rightBar` this css

```
#rightBar
{
    float: right;
    position:relative;
}
```

and for `#hideshowBookmark`

```
#hideshowBookmark
{
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(#81BEF7,#2E9AFE);
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 0;
    margin-top: 170px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

Comment: Just wonder do you know why when I slide the div out, all the components are moving? Do you know how to make their position stay?

Answer (score 0):

Change css to this class to following:

```
#hideshowBookmark
{
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(#81BEF7,#2E9AFE);
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 0;
    margin-top: 170px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 7px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76FX8/4/)

Comment: It works! Thanks. By the way, what did you added? Could you please explain a little bit to me?

Comment: Hmm i'm not very good at explanations but i will give it a try. With position absolute you can place elements exactly where you want it. So i change it position to absolute and with right to 7 px i placed it to the right side :)

Comment: However, with `position:absolute;` you're completely removing your element from the flow (`float` is doing nothing), so it can get a bit tricky to create your layout. The position of the element is absolute to its parent, so if you change the parent, you will also change the child.

Also, if you have 20 elements, placing everything with `absolute` is not a good practice, it's better to keep them floated.

Comment: Tottaly aggre with you @Cthulhu. First you can remove float:right indeed and if you know how to use position:absolute is fine :)

Comment: @Alek Just wonder do you know why when I slide the div out, all the components are moving? Do you know how to make their position stay?

Comment: Sorry @Gwen didn't have time to answer. Hope i will later today :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by moving the `rightContent` div out of the `rightBar` div, removed the float attributes from the buttons and added a float attribute to the `rightContent` div.

See also the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86zwD/)

Comment: Just wonder do you know why when I slide the div out, all the components are moving? Do you know how to make their position stay?

Comment: it is because the width is changing and the components use the space htey have. With this method you cannot make them stay with this method.

Comment: Do you have any idea to fix this?